# Where can I get a list of all iOS elements?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

What is a good resource for a list of iOS GUI elements?

The official documentation, such as the [UIPickerView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) do not include images, and while sometimes the official overview documentation has images, they are not easily found.

The closest thing I have found is iOS photoshop templates (including the awesome [Teehan Lax one](http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-5-gui-psd-iphone-4s/) ), but they don't reference the class name, or have any common third party controls.

**Edit**: A web based site would be great, so I can share with others who do not have Xcode, or browse on an iPad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Apple Developer portal has a [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) listing all the UI elements for iOS and also goes into what their various uses are. Here's an excerpt for how they describe a UITextView:

> **Text View**
>   A text view accepts and displays multiple lines of text. To learn more about defining a text view in your code, see [UITextView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006898).
>   
>   **Appearance and Behavior**
>   A text view is a rounded rectangle of any height. A text view supports scrolling when the content is too large to fit inside its bounds.
> If the text view supports user editing, a keyboard appears when the user taps inside the text view. The keyboard’s input method and layout are determined by the user’s language settings. When users tap the button labeled “.?123,” the keyboard changes to display numbers, punctuation marks, and a few common symbols.
>   **Guidelines**
>   You have control over the font, color, and alignment of the text in a text view, but only as they apply to the entirety of the text. In other words, you can’t change any of these properties for only part of the text. The default font is the system font and the default color is black, because these tend to be the most readable. The default for the alignment property is left (you can change it to center or right).
> If you must enable variable fonts, colors, or alignments within a view that displays text, you can use a web view instead of a text view, and style the text using HTML.
>  You can also specify different keyboard styles, depending on the type of content you expect users to enter. For a description of the styles you can use, see “Text Field.”

If you simply want to see a list of UI Elements and not the descriptions, go to the sidebar on the left and click on the disclosure arrow next to "iOS UI Elements Usage Guidelines", and it'll have a list of general categories like "Bars", "Content Views", "Controls", etc. From there you can click the disclosure arrow next to the category headings to see individual UI elements. The image below illustrates what I mean:

[image]

Comment: That would do it, thanks! For some reason I never found that page.

Comment: The link is dead and I believe the original document is deprecated.
Here is a fresh [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1).

Comment: I updated the URL in the answer so it'll still work for people.

Answer (score 2):

You can take an in-depth look at UIElements inside this page of documentation [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/uikit_catalog_creating_and_customizing_views_and_controls)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a list of GUI elements of the standard framework, you can check Interface Builder for them, and even change the configuration to show the possible ways to create them. Storyboard also gives you some flexibility to add content to it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I also sometimes need to talk with less technical people, so it would be great to have a web based resource.

Comment: @qegal - sorry I wasn't clear in my last comment. My challenge is that I am discussing a UIDatePicker with a client and would like to be able to link to a page with an example.